# Table of frames - anything better than <table>...<iframe>

Tags: jquery, iframe, html

I would like to create a 3x3 table where each cell contains an iframe with some external page (my actual use case is to edit 9 Google Docs simultaneously).

The only solution I know of is:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <iframe src="docs.google.com/myfile1">
    </td>
    <td>
      <iframe src="docs.google.com/myfile2">
    </td>
...
</table>
```

Is there a smarter way of doing this, perhaps with JQuery?

Comment: Nope, there isn't. The only way to import other pages is using `iFrame`s. Some might argue that `div`'s are a cleaner way to create the 9 cell's. However, it doesn't really matter much.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this approach.

Comment: `table`'s are for displaying tabulated data.  `div`'s are for page layout.  Yes, it matters.

Answer (score 0):

you may use divs

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#1").load("docs.google.com/myfile1");
$("#2").load("docs.google.com/myfile2");
});
```

Comment: +1 for using `div`'s instead of tables. But -1 for using `.load()` across domains.  [It will not work](http://api.jquery.com/load/).  _"Due to browser security restrictions, most 'Ajax' requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol."_

Comment: Besides that, even if there was not a cross domain restriction, it [still would not work](http://api.jquery.com/load/) because you are no longer interacting with a Google page; you are simply loading remote content... _"jQuery uses the browser's `.innerHTML` property to parse the retrieved document and insert it into the current document. During this process, browsers often filter elements from the document such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by `.load()` may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved directly by the browser."_